# Wordpress embedded twitter, instagram not scrollable on mobile iphone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I just started using wordpress and `www.PlanetWeb.ca` is my first site, but for the life of me I can not figure out why I can not scroll on mobile devices when embedding youtube, instagram , facebook comments, etc. Do I need to put `<div>` around embed?

Thanks for helping me

[Here is one example where you can not scroll](http://www.planetweb.ca/top-lists/canadian-tech-entrepreneurs-twitter-15-must-follow/)

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe has the attribute `scrolling="no"`. Change it to 'yes'?

```
<iframe id="rufous-sandbox" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none;" title="Twitter analytics iframe"></iframe>
```